# How can I find element indices in kdb?

Tags: kdb

How can i determine the index of first and last occurence of an element in a list in kdb. The list obviously has repeat values and is not sorted. The list contains only floats (prices) if that matters. I tried using bin and binr but its not giving the desired results.

Comment: From the documentation for `bin`: The items of the left argument should be sorted non-descending

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May I suggest an alternative (simpler? easier to read? more general?) solution:

```
q)list:1 2 3 2 4 2 5f  
q)list=2.0
0101010b
q)where list=2.0
1 3 5
q)first where list=2.0
1
q)last where list=2.0
5
```

Comment: can be nicely combined into a one liner
     `q)(first;last)@\: where list=2`

Answer (score 0):

figured it out.

```
pxs?1b /gives first and 
(count pxs) - (reverse pxs)?5222.4 /gives last
```

Comment: I would be careful of using ?, unless you know for sure the element is in the list. If it is not, it will give you the length of the list.